# Is there any way to set single row fetched database values in textbox in Codeigniter without using loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want am fetching single row values from database, my data is getting fetched from Database. But how can I view it in the textbox in view without using loop as it is only 1 row data.

**My Contoller**

```
public function index(){
    $data_key = ENCRYPT_KEY;
    $user_id = $_SESSION['pat_user_id'];
    $this->db->select('fname, lname, email');
    $result= $this->User_edit_model->get_where(array('uname'=>$user_id));
    $this->load->view('user_edit', $result);
    print_r_custom($result);
    var_dump($result);
}
```

**View.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php echo $user_records->fname; ?>" class="fname form-control">
            <label class="form-control-placeholder label1" for="fname">Given Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**The output error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRwbl.png)

Comment: From the var_dump output shown in your output error, it seems both $result and $user_records are array. So you have to use array index to access the properties. Try $result[0].user_records[0].fname etc.

Comment: either use `row_array` in model, or use `user_records[0]`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Thanks for your time & help. You have resolved my query. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use query like this:

```
$query = $db->query("YOUR QUERY"); 
// "YOUR QUERY" should be something like this"SELECT fname, lname, email from user_tbl WHERE uname = $user_id"

$row = $query->getRow();

if (isset($row)) {
    echo $row->fname;
    echo $row->lname;
    echo $row->email;
}
```

You can see the details here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows

You can also try this like:

```
$result = $this->db->select('fname, lname, email')->get_where(array('uname'=>$user_id))->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, Operations related to DB should be in the model by MVC idea.

Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $data_key = ENCRYPT_KEY;
    $user_id = $_SESSION['pat_user_id'];
   
    $result= $this->User_edit_model->get_userInfo(array('uname'=>$user_id));
    $this->load->view('user_edit', $result);
}
```

Model: User_edit_model

```
public function get_userInfo($where){
    $this->db->select('fname, lname, email');
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->db->get("table_name")->row_array();
}
```